# Difference between error reporting in linux and windows in php

Tags: php, linux, windows, error-reporting

I am coding and testing php application on Linux but it is running also on Windows machine.
I have enabled error reporting by

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Problem is that when I run my code on Linux machine there are not showed any errors.
But on windows machine there is a lot of error like:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\IS\lib\JLMySQL.php on line 8
>
> Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\IS\pages\index.php on line 17
>
> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\IS\pages\index.php on line 144

My question is, how can I show this errors on Linux machine?

Comment: Are you running the same versions of PHP on both machines? with the same modules enabled?

Comment: I have on my PC Linux 5.4.9, Windows server have now 5.5.5, but before was there 5.3.27 and still same errors. And modules are enabled same on both Windows and Linux